# Continue MERGE after EXCEPTION

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql, merge

Is it possible to continue a `MERGE` after an `EXCEPTION` ?

```
MERGE INTO copy_emp c
     USING employees e
     ON (c.employee_id = e.employee_id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET
       c.first_name     = e.first_name,
       c.last_name      = e.last_name,
       c.email          = e.email,
       c.phone_number   = e.phone_number,
       c.hire_date      = e.hire_date,
       c.job_id         = e.job_id,
       c.salary         = e.salary,
       c.commission_pct = e.commission_pct,
       c.manager_id     = e.manager_id,
       c.department_id  = e.department_id
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT VALUES(e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name,
          e.email, e.phone_number, e.hire_date, e.job_id,
          e.salary, e.commission_pct, e.manager_id,
          e.department_id);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        -- ?????
```

Apart retrieve the ID of the row who threw the exception and restart the `MERGE` ignoring this ID I do not see how to do.

I'm using Oracle Database 10.

Comment: Isn't it possible to first call for a result set that has no major errors that have to be fixed manually, then use that for this query? Otherwise you'd have to do things like insert default values into the missing or incorrect ones, which is something you definitely do NOT want to do seeing as people could end up in departments or positions they aren't.

Comment: @user3427079, and how would you scale it with big, bigger, huge applications running complex ETL batch processes? Would you fix each error manually and then proceed?

Comment: This is not the place for these discussions, but when it comes to keeping track of who you are paying to do what, I'd run all correct and acceptable data first then start checking the ones that are obviously wrong in a dangerous way. Like paying your janitor ten thousands because of a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the [error_logging_clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#BGBEIACB). (The link is for the insert because in the documentation of [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm#BGBDCCEC) it says that it has the same behavior as an insert.

For your case :

```
-- You create your Log Table
EXECUTE DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG('copy_emp', 'TAB_ERR_COPY_EMP');


    MERGE INTO copy_emp c
     USING employees e
     ON (c.employee_id = e.employee_id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET
       c.first_name     = e.first_name,
       c.last_name      = e.last_name,
       c.email          = e.email,
       c.phone_number   = e.phone_number,
       c.hire_date      = e.hire_date,
       c.job_id         = e.job_id,
       c.salary         = e.salary,
       c.commission_pct = e.commission_pct,
       c.manager_id     = e.manager_id,
       c.department_id  = e.department_id
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT VALUES(e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name,
          e.email, e.phone_number, e.hire_date, e.job_id,
          e.salary, e.commission_pct, e.manager_id,
          e.department_id)
    LOG ERRORS INTO TAB_ERR_COPY_EMP('TAG_STATEMENT') REJECT LIMIT 100;
```

Please note that there are some limitations for the error_logging_clause. From the documentation :

1. The following conditions cause the statement to fail and roll back
   without invoking the error logging capability:

   - Violated deferred constraints.
   - Any direct-path INSERT or MERGE operation that raises a unique
     constraint or index violation.
   - Any update operation UPDATE or MERGE that raises a unique constraint
     or index violation).
2. You cannot track errors in the error logging table for LONG, LOB, or
   object type columns. However, the table that is the target of the
   DML operation can contain these types of columns.

   - If you create or modify the corresponding error logging table so that
     it contains a column of an unsupported type, and if the name of that
     column corresponds to an unsupported column in the target DML table,
     then the DML statement fails at parse time.
   - If the error logging table does not contain any unsupported column
     types, then all DML errors are logged until the reject limit of
     errors is reached. For rows on which errors occur, column values with
     corresponding columns in the error logging table are logged along
     with the control information.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to avoid termination. I have been mostly using `FORALL SAVE EXCEPTIONS` clause.

In Oracle Database 10g and higher, PL/SQL offers three options for “continuing past an exception,”which really means avoiding termination of the execution of the current block. Please read this excellent article by Steven Feuerstein, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-mar/o29plsql-085126.html