# How can I set the MERGE operation to continue execution after Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

Can I set up the MERGE operation to continue its execution after failed constraints, for example attempts of inserting NULLs, FK or PK? I have a simple MERGE

```
MERGE Test1 AS t1
USING Test2 AS t2
ON t1.a = t2.d
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN 
        INSERT(a, b, c)
        VALUES(d, e, f)
```

I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524519/continue-merge-after-exception) that with Oracle DB it is possible to put [LOG ERRORS] instruction after MERGE in order to skip the first N errors and just log them:

```
LOG ERRORS INTO TAB_ERR_COPY_EMP('TAG_STATEMENT') REJECT LIMIT 100;
```

Can I have similar workaround with SQL SERVER 2016 SP1 or is it a bad practice overall?

Why I need it - I am trying to create a customazible MERGE (with N tables and N fields) for daily integration with other systems and sometimes there can be different data of different types or without satisfying some FKs. So I want to skip some problematic fields but have most of my data integrated.

Comment: SQL Server has no such provisions for `MERGE` (or any other statement). You can manually add conditions to the `MATCHED` / `NOT MATCHED` clauses to redirect specific errors into new tables, but this would not catch all errors in general. Advanced scenarios like these are better handled with client code (like Integration Services); T-SQL is too rigorous and offers too few hooks for inspecting problematic data. If you have to use T-SQL, you're better off using multiple `INSERT` / `DELETE` stages to filter data (wrapped in a transaction if necessary); a single `MERGE` is too ambitious.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f691d4b6-553e-41f5-bdc7-1253fa9abf26/catch-exception-and-continue-the-execution?forum=sqlgetstarted.

Comment: @Sorix, thanks, I have seen this article, however both approaches I suppose won't be suitable for me - 'row by row' takes a lot of time for >1000k rows and SSIS we just don't use at this server. I thought about writing some T-SQL procedures which would be easy to read and mainrtain for future developers.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks, I am thinking about T-SQL option and I will try to implement `BULK INSERT` as it provides MAXERRORS which will work, I hope

Comment: Probably not -- per the docs, `MAXERRORS` does not apply to constraint checking. You can, of course, ignore constraints while bulk loading and check things afterwards, but discarding things based on constraint violations is not on the menu.